# Crear tabla con UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta en Access que la tengo que pasar a SQL Server

```
INSERT INTO 
    Out_MTK ( Id_MTK, Fijo1, Fijo2)
SELECT 
    Aux_Mtk_Red_Familia.Expr1, Aux_Mtk_Red_Familia.Fijo1, Aux_Mtk_Red_Familia.Fijo2
FROM 
    Aux_Mtk_Red_Familia
```

El problema es que Aux_Mtk_Red_Familia no existe, es un UNION de dos tablas

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    Aux_Mtk_Red_Familia_Parte1
UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM
        Aux_Mtk_Red_Familia_Parte2
```

Como hago para que la consulta del UNION me cree una tabla y así pueda concatenar las dos consultas en una?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la tabla `Out_MTK` ya existe, simplemente debes hacer:

```
INSERT INTO Out_MTK(Id_MTK, Fijo1, Fijo2)
SELECT * 
FROM Aux_Mtk_Red_Familia_Parte1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM Aux_Mtk_Red_Familia_Parte2;
```

Si la tabla no existe y la quieres crear con los datos de ese `UNION ALL`, entonces usa:

```
SELECT * 
INTO Out_MTK
FROM Aux_Mtk_Red_Familia_Parte1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM Aux_Mtk_Red_Familia_Parte2;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba pensando en hacerlo como en Access donde había que crear una nueva tabla cuando la solución era mucho mas sencilla

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti No hay problema. La verdad es que no conozco bien la sintaxis de Access, pero muchas veces tiende a sobrecomplicar las cosas

Comment: En Access la consulta que haces con UNION te crea una nueva tabla